# Getting chrome.getAuthToken to work inside a script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension that retrieves data from a user's Google Drive and inserts it into an arbitrary page. I've gotten the OAuth to work, but I can't seem to get access to the token (which I can see is set via `chrome://identity-internals`).

The issue here is that when the Chrome extension nav bar button is clicked, I fire a request to execute `test.js`. `test.js` apparently has no concept of `chrome.identity`, but it needs that information to make an XHR request. I've tried

1. Storing the auth token in localStorage so that test.js can retrieve it (no luck)
2. Nesting the test.js inside the AuthToken request (not sure how to actually pass the variable into the file and retrieve it).

Are there any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {

            chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function(token) {
                // This works
                alert(token);
                // This doesn't work
                localStorage.setItem("authtoken", token);

            });
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                // This file needs access to the authtoken
                // but within test.js, chrome.identity is undefined.
                "file": "test.js"
            }, function () {

            });     

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`localStorage` (effectively it's `window.localStorage`) is stored per origin (scheme + hostname + port number), and extensions have their own one in privileged components that can access restricted chrome.* API (some are listed as exceptions in [content scripts docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)), namely popup and background/event page, options, and other pages with a URL like `chrome-extension://abc.....` (abc... is an extension ID).

`localStorage` of a web page belongs to its own origin such as `https://www.google.com`.

Content scripts run in the context of web page, so they can't access extension's `localStorage` directly. They see `localStorage` of their web page's origin only.

- **Solution 1: use another `executeScript` to set a variable** that will be used by the content script injected from a file:

  ```js
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
      chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function(token) {
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
              code: 'var token=' + JSON.stringify(token) + ';'
          }, function() {
              chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "test.js"}, function() {
              });
          });
      });     
  });
  ```

  JSON-serialization is used in order not to bother escaping special characters and be able to pass objects.
- **Solution 2: use [messaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)** to pass data once the content script is injected:

  ```js
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
      chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function(token) {
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "test.js"}, function() {
              chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {token: token});
          });
      });     
  });
  ```

  content script:

  ```js
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (msg.token) {
          document.getElementById('token').textContent = msg.token;
          //nowYouCanProcessToken(msg.token);
      }
  });
  ```
- **Solution 3: use [chrome.storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)** accessible both from a content script and the abovementioned privileged parts of an extension.

  ```js
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
      chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function(token) {
          chrome.storage.local.set({token: token}, function() {
              chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "test.js"}, function() {
              });
          });     
      });     
  });
  ```

  content script:

  ```js
  chrome.storage.local.get('token', function(data) {
      if (data.token) {
          document.getElementById('token').textContent = data.token;
          //nowYouCanProcessToken(data.token);
      }
  });
  ```